# Trying to make the two navigation menus the same width

Tags: html, css, menu

Trying to make the top menu be centered and same width as the menu below. So pushing the social media icons to the right and the menu items to the left to even up with the main nav menu below. Example is: https://www.nelsonforensics.com/ as both the menus are ligned up perfectly. Our Website is: http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>Horizontal Navigation Bar w/Rollover Effect</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 

#navbar ul { 
  height: inherit;
  /* margin: 0; REMOVE THIS*/
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right; 
  background-color: #000; 
}

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 10px 5px;
  height: inherit;
  border-left: 1px dashed #fff;
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: bold; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
/*     background-color: #000;  */
    } 

#navbar ul li:hover { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    } 
#navbar ul li:hover a { 
    color: #000 !important; 
    } 

    #navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{

   top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
              the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
              from the top of the page.*/

  }

.social-icon-wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px dashed #fff;
}
    .social-icon-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.social-icon {
  width: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

 .submit-btn {
  background-color: green !important;
  border-left: 1px dashed #fff !important;
  }
--> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<!--  -->
<div id="navbar"> 
  <ul class="container"> 
      <ul>
        <li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/tonPA8V.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/fEvitJl.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/UiwMSrt.png"></a></li><!--  --><li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="tel:+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/stephens-university/">Stephens University</a></li><!--  --><li class="submit-btn" ><a href="http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/submit-assignment/">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup and the css is a bit messy, most probably it is generated by a wordpress theme or something.

Your top `#navbar` is not aligned with your `.main_menu`, because the `.main_menu` has the bootstrap `container` class.

A quick solution, would be to add the `container` class to your navbar's `ul` as well. You will also need to remove the `margin: 0` rule of your `#navbar ul` because it overwrites the default `.container` margin rule (you can explicitly set `margin-bottom: 0` if you want.

Finally, i guess you will need to add the same black `background-color` to your `#navbar` because it might look a bit awkward now that it will be contained - but this is a design decision (and I am not a designer).

So, I repeat the code that has changed.

```css
#navbar ul { 
  height: inherit;
  /* margin: 0; REMOVE THIS*/
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Suggested */
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right; 
  background-color: #000; 
} 

/* Suggested for aesthetic reasons */
#navbar {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar"> 
  <ul class="container">

  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped, but like you said the top bar has been cut off on the sides. How can i fix that?

Comment: Add the background rule for the #navbar.

Comment: i did but still no luck. i edited the post to show you what it looks like now

Comment: I still don't see the `#navbar` rule for `background-color: #000`. You need to add the `#navbar {  background-color: #000; }` rule.

Comment: that helped the background but now it is too thick

Comment: In the place that you removed the `margin: 0`, you can add the `margin-bottom: 0` as suggested in my code. This will remove the extra margin.